# JPA Repository and Spring-data-rest baseURi is /profile

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Just learning springboot (and newish to java: from .NET world)

Too PS course on spring-data and spring-data-rest. All went well

Made a test project connection to MS SQlServer. Created a few JPA Repos and unit tests pass for FindAll

I don't have a base-uri set in app properties and when explore the rest interface (with Postman) everything appears under /profile.

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile"
        },
        "users": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/users"
        },
        "tasks": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/tasks"
        }
    }
}
```

first question is, where does /profile come from?

Comment: Search your project for `@RequestMapping`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a **base path** (url). It's a [normal work of SDR](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#metadata.alps):

> A profile link, as defined in [RFC 6906](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6906), is a place to include application-level details. The [ALPS draft spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-amundsen-richardson-foster-alps-00) is meant to define a particular profile format, which we explore later in this section.
>
> If you navigate into the profile link at `localhost:8080/profile`, you see content resembling the following:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "_links" : {
>     "self" : {
>       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
>     },
>     "persons" : {
>       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/persons"
>     },
>     "addresses" : {
>       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/addresses"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

To work with your entities you have to use these links:

- http://localhost:8080/users
- http://localhost:8080/tasks

By the way you can set 'base path' in [three ways](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.changing-base-uri):

1. In 'application.properties`

   `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api`
2. Registering a bean

   ```java
   @Bean
   public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {

     return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {

       @Override
       public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
         config.setBasePath("/api");
       }
     };
   }
   ```
3. With a custom implementation of `RepositoryRestConfigurer`

   ```java
   @Component
   public class CustomizedRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
       config.setBasePath("/api");
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detail

Comment: @Cepr0 It's seems a bit inaccurate to state "it's not a base path" when the Spring Data REST configuration options you reference to change it call it a "base path".